# what is the physical significance of this phenomena?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let's suppose that i'm going to ride a motorcycle , so what i'll do first is accelerate , then i'll achieve some velocity and after that my position will change ,mathematically..

$$ \dfrac{d^{2}x(t)}{dt^{2}} \rightarrow \dfrac{dx(t)}{dt} \rightarrow x(t)$$
so here integration which takes place step by step , then if differentiation is the reverse process of integration then how it happens in this case ?

Comment: If you want it's ***Physical*** Significance, probably you will get best answer on Physics SE


  : http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: okay let me post it there thanks

Comment: but isn't there a certain time lag between each operation ? like take i'm at position x_{1} with velocity v_{1} now i want to achieve velocity v_{2} at position x_{2} , like this ? @MorganRodgers

Comment: At any given time, you have acceleration, velocity, and position. At time $t$, your cumulative acceleration yields your current velocity (i.e., integrate over acceleration to find velocity). Similarly, your position at time $t$ is given by your cumulative velocity up until that point in time. Now, at any given time, you can find your instantaneous velocity by differentiating your position function, similarly you can find your acceleration by differentiating your velocity function. This is how these three things all fit together.